# Notify when popover is removed - iOS

Tags: ios, dropbox, uipopovercontroller

I am using dropbox sharing, and there is a view (dropbox framework has the references) that gets displayed when I try to login to dropbox. But there is a bug in the framework, it doesn't make a callback when the screen is dismissed by pressing a button on some alert view.

I need a notification when this view disappears.

In iPhone, using `viewDidAppear` was serving all purpose, because I have to do some generic things which can be done everytime the view appears.

But in iPad, it probably gets displayed as a popup. (like `MFMailComposer` with a black translucent background, but smaller). So there is no notification for when it disappears.

And I don't have the reference to the popover. (Assuming it is a popover)

(Can I use KVO somehow and observe the array `subviews` of the root view controller somehow?)

**Update:** This bug has been solved in the latest dropbox core api Build.

Comment: Have you reported the bug to Dropbox? And could you explain more what you mean by "pressing a button on some alert view?"

Comment: I have notified to the dropbox guys, and they agreed to the fact that it is a bug. Probably will be solved in their next release.